# In Swift, how do I add a where constraint is equatable inside a protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I want to write a generic `deck` of cards class which I can use in different applications and it currently has a protocol but I am unable to add a `where Element : Equatable` to the protocol as it complains that:

> Instance method requirement 'find' cannot add constraint
> 'Self.Element: Equatable' on 'Self'

This error is thrown on the line when I try to add:

`func find(_ card: Element) -> Int? where Element: Equatable`

to the protocol.

Swift Code follows,

```
protocol DeckDelegate: AnyObject {
    associatedtype Element
    var size: Int { get }
    var isEmpty: Bool { get }
    var cards:[Element] { get set }
    func push(_ element: Element)
    func pop() -> Element?
    func find(_ card: Element) -> Int? where Element: Equatable
}

class Deck<Element> {
    func find(_ card: Element) -> Int? where Element : Equatable {
        return cards.firstIndex(of: card)
    }
    
    var size: Int {
        return cards.count
    }
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return (cards.count == 0)
    }
    
    internal var cards: [Element] = []
    
    func push(_ element: Element) {
        cards.append(element)
    }
    
    func pop() -> Element? {
        // TBD
    }
    
}
```

My question is, how do I add the constraint to the Swift protocol?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the relationship between `DeckDelegate` and `Deck`? Is `Deck` supposed to have a property of type `any DeckDelegate<Element>` or something like that?

Comment: And what do you mean by `where Element: Equatable` on the protocol? Did you mean to say `func find<E: Equatable>(_ card: E) -> Int? where Self.Element == E`?

Comment: Why do you need a protocol for your generic type? Start simple and have only one of them, since you say you want to write a generic class I say go for that and ditch the protocol.

Comment: I am just learning about this kind of relationship between generics, elements, equatables, etc.  There isn't any relationship between deck delegate and deck, the reason is because I might want to make a new class that needs to conform to the deck delegate

Comment: Yes, I want to find a card that is equitable within the array / deck where it matches

Comment: Okay, I will just keep it simple for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a `find` function be available **only if** the `Element` is `Equatble`, but you don't want to introduce a new generic type inside the function signature itself. So you need to extend the protocol instead:

```
extension DeckDelegate where Element: Equatable {
    func find(_ card: Element) -> Int? where Element: Equatable {
        cards.firstIndex(of: card)
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I will try this out.   Thank you for your help -- though I do now realise if I keep it simple I don't need the protocol, but I was learning about it just to see how it worked